# Валидация input[type=file]

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Всем здравствуйте :)
Подскажите как можно сделать валидацию input[type=file] при помощи jquery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если собрались проверять расширение загружаемого файла, то можно так, плюс [живой пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/94Sbe/):

```
var filesExt = ['jpg', 'gif', 'png']; // массив расширений
$('input[type=file]').change(function(){
    var parts = $(this).val().split('.');
    if(filesExt.join().search(parts[parts.length - 1]) != -1){
        alert('Good!');
    } else {
        alert('WTF?!');
    }
});
```

Comment: ой да. «s» лишнее было.
Вот есть форма отправки файла и кнопка. И если юзер не выбрал файл, но нажал на кнопку, то пусть ему JS сообщит, что файл не выбран.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, а как быть, когда у нас у  input[type=file] стоит multiple="true", т.е. загружается сразу несколько изображений?
Нашла примерное решение здесь http://web-lucas.ru/php/multiple_file_uploader/

Comment: задайте вопрос, только полностью описывающий вашу проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Для html5 есть атрибут [accept](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/accept).

А для старых браузеров через JS:

```
var R_ACCEPT_IMAGE = /\.(gif|jpe?g|tiff?|png|bmp)$/i;
var input = ducoment.getElementById('files');
input.onchange = function () {
   var status = R_ACCEPT_IMAGE.test(input.value);
   console.log(status); // true или false
};
```

Comment: Атрибут accept не запрещает пользователю выбирать файлы другого формата, он лишь устанавливает фильтр, а в новом FF вообще по умолчанию выбор всех файлов.